# Dynamic pipelines in apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

[image]

I have a generic input request which contains input that needs to be transformed and saved. If the resulting output needs to be transformed, i would implement a new processor (transformer) for it.

```
class Request {
  Input input;
  Transformer transformer;
  Output output;
}
```

Based on the message read from the source i generate a graph of required transforms that's depicted in the image, its based on the configuration for each input lets say for different customers. Here the pipeline i generate for every message is dynamic. i.e

```
Graph<Request> gRequests;
```

Child transforms input is dependent on successful completion of parent transform.

**Is there any way i can generate an dynamic apache beam pipeline for this? or whats the best approach?**

As of now i am flattening every transform into a sequential list of transforms based on input and output and passing through every pipeline step, it performs the transform if its configured or else just skips.

Sequential list of transformers.

[image]

For every new transform needed it rearranges the pipeline. Thats the expected flow!!. But if i can chain transforms based on input and my customer configuration It would be a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can't generate Beam pipeline in the runtime - it should be known in advance since before actual run, the runner will process a DAG of your pipeline and translate it into a pipeline of your data processing system (e.g. Spark, Flink, Dataflow, etc).

In the same time, you can leverage [branches in your pipeline](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/design-your-pipeline/#branching-pcollections) that incorporate different transforms and process different records with specific branches depending on your conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i have incorporated branching where a transform can be run in parallel for a particular input.